# TableView with inset grouped style: Have rounded corners even with hidden cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a table of the type inset grouped style. Depending on some selections I want to hide some cells by reducing their height to 0. Now is there anyway to still show rounded corners even if the respective cell has height 0? Or how would you do that? I don't want to "delete" the cell, otherwise it is much more complex to keep track of the cells for me.

[image]

Comment: "I want to hide some cells by reducing their height to 0" What about instead using another mecanism to not showing cells?

Comment: How? I don't want to delete them

Comment: @MichiZH Did u find a way to solve this? I am also having same issues

Comment: @MichiZH Same here ... any solution?