# Create a tableView inside UIView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

Hi :) I'm having a tableView and I want to have a tableView inside my UITableViewCell, now I was thinking to create a custom tableView inside UIView class and then present it inside the UITableViewCell using UIView, I'm wondering is it possible or I'm approaching the problem wrong :)

Here's a picture of what I would like to achieve: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaCP1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Although you CAN add a `UITableView` to any `UIView`, that means also to a `UITableViewCell`, what you are trying to achieve looks like a `UITableView` with `UITableView.Style.insetGrouped`.

**This new style for table views is available at iOS13.**

Just initialize your table view with this style, e.g.:

```swift
let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .insetGrouped)
```

You can see the documentation here: (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style/insetgrouped)

In this thread, there is the screenshot of this `UITableView.Style`:

[TableView with inset grouped style: Have rounded corners even with hidden cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61502471/tableview-with-inset-grouped-style-have-rounded-corners-even-with-hidden-cells)

Comment: @Iaka Oh I see, well the problem is my app only works for users with iOS 10 and above :\

Comment: Okay I found out I can do it like :     let tableView = UITableViewController(style: .grouped)
 the thing is, is that possible to do a uitableviewcontroller inside UIView?

Comment: You can add a UITableView (not a UITableViewController) to a UIView.

Comment: However, I think you should be able to subclass `UITableView` and modify its appearance to be similar to `.insetGrouped` instead of adding a `UITableView` to a `UIView`.

Comment: well i added a tableView inside. a UIView, the thing is I can't use .insetGrouped due to the fact that is only for iOS13+ and the app got users for iOS10+ lol but thanks for the help I solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that kind of look by using [inset grouped style](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style/insetgrouped)
on UITableView and by adding [sections](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/adding_headers_and_footers_to_table_sections) to UITableView